# DVI-D and DVI-I cable

Tags: dvi

I have DVI-I slot in video card and I have DVI-D cable. Is that fine to use the cable for that slot? because my monitor have DVI-D slot.

Comment: DVI-I can go through DVI-D cables, just not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since you're not trying to use the DVI-A signals.